# Iterating through controls on a form

Tags: controls, c++builder

I am using C++ Builder. I want to locate several string grids that I have located on different tab sheets of a page control. I know how to iterate through the child controls of a specific control. In my case, each string grid is contained under a separate tab sheet control.  My question is, is there a list of all controls in an app, without regards to the hierarchy of where they are contained?

Answer (score 0):

There is such a list: `Application->Components`, consider code below

```
for (int i = 0; i < Application->ComponentCount; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < Application->Components[i]->ComponentCount; j++) {
    if (dynamic_cast<TStringGrid*>(Application->Components[i]->Components[j])){
      //there is your TStringGrid* regardless of a place in application
    }
  }
}
```

You may as well iterate through your tab controls children if you are sure that your string grids are only there.